# Reactive Programming - Webflux Webfilter not behaving properly

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm a bit new to reactive programming, and I'm trying to assemble the following: using Java, Springboot 2, Webflux, and reactor core, I want to handle very specific requests that need extra authentication. So I'm implementing a `WebFilter` with a series of steps:

- Capture the path and the method of the request. Check if the combination exists and needs specific authentication with the `accessPointService.getAccessPointAuthorizationRequirement` method (returns a Mono with a Boolean).
- Since I have CSRF and Spring security configured, I need both csrf token and springsession credentials. I make a GET and a POST request for the credentials.
- Then with the credentials, I simply make a POST request to a service (authcheck) that can do a series of security checks (the service is OK, works fine from Postman and Angular).
- After that, I need to retrieve the body, convert it to String, and inspect it. Right now this does not happen.

The filter

```
@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, final WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

        //client for specific requests.
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
        //get request for the CSRF cookie.
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> getRequest = webClient.get()
                .uri("/login");
        //post request for the spring security session cookie.
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> postRequest = webClient.post()
                .uri("/login")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "username")
                        .with("password", "password"));
                        //services that checks if the given request needs extra authentication
        return accessPointService.getAccessPointAuthorizationRequirement(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getMethod().toString().toUpperCase(), serverWebExchange.getRequest().getPath().toString())
                .log()
                //gets the csrf token from the GET request
                .flatMap(isRequired -> getRequest.exchangeToMono(response -> Mono.just(response.cookies().getFirst("XSRF-TOKEN").getValue())))
                //combines the previous token with the POST request SESSION cookie,
                //THEN secures the last request with both credentials
                .zipWith(postRequest.exchangeToMono(resp -> Mono.just(resp.cookies().getFirst("SESSION").getValue())),
                        AuthenticationFilter::secureAuthRequest)
                //gets the exchange from the request and converts the body into a String
                .flatMap(AuthenticationFilter::getRequestExchange)
                //code to validate if it's doing something. Not implemented yet because it never executes.
                .flatMap(s -> Mono.just(s.equals("")))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    throw (CustomException) e;//breaks the execution
                })
                .then(webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange));//continues the execution
    }
```

The `secureAuthRequest` and `getRequestExchange` methods invoked

```
//adds the springsession cookie and csrf cookie to the request
private static WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> secureAuthRequest(String csrf, String spring) {

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = webClient.post()
                .uri("/authcheck")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        request.header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrf);
        request.cookies( cookies -> cookies.add(  "XSRF-TOKEN", csrf) );
        request.header("Authorization", spring);
        return request;
    }

//gets the body as string.
private static Mono<String> getRequestExchange(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> securedReq) {

        return securedReq.exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
    }
```

However, when a request is bound to be authenticated, the log is the following:

```
2021-10-26 23:57:18.760  INFO 6860 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.Just.4                      : | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
2021-10-26 23:57:18.761  INFO 6860 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.Just.4                      : | request(unbounded)
2021-10-26 23:57:18.761  INFO 6860 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.Just.4                      : | onNext(true)
2021-10-26 23:57:18.762  INFO 6860 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.Just.4                      : | onComplete()
```

As far as I know, the stream of data starts with a subscription and a posterior request (which I think returns a TRUE from the `accessPointService.getAccessPointAuthorizationRequirement` method Mono value, if I'm wrong please correct me), but then the 'onComplete()' log shows up. I don't know exactly what the onComplete() log means, since it's being shown before the execution of the getRequestExchange method (which is invoked). The `Mono.just(s.equals(""))` piece of code never executes.

I've read a lot about how 'nothing happens until you subscribe', but I still don't know why the reactive flow is being invoked at all if I never explicitly subscribe to the stream, and neither I know how to implement it, since it only returns a Disposable (I guess I can throw exceptions from within?). Also, I hear about decoupling when multiple subscribers are being invoked, so I tried to  avoid them as possible.

Any help regarding reactive programming, reactor-core, or the specific flow and how to improve it it's appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Your code is very hard to follow as tou are trying to do imperativ coding instead of reactice coding. I cant tell you exactly what is wrong but i can give you some advice. First, do not build a webclient on each call. create your webclients in beans and autowire them in. Divide your code into functions, doing one thing, dont do some things here and then some things there. You get the CSRF token, you extract it, then you pass it downstream. Use either a wrapper object or pass information down using tuples.

Comment: Refeain from using Mono<Boolean> either an operation worked and will return a Mono<T> or if not you return a Mono<Void> (using Mono.empty()> or it errored and you return a Mono.error. And lastly, writing custom security is bad practice. There are security standards out there and by not following them you are potentially putting all your data at risk.

Comment: And you dont subscribe, the consumer subscribes. Which in this case is the calling client. Thats how your code gets executed, you return a producer to the client.

Comment: I didn't use functions too much in the draft to see better how the operations were handled, and you are right about using them. I took your advice on the Webclient, so I created a custom WebClientProvider as a bean that handles that. On the other hand, I appreciate the clarification on the consumer subscribing, not the method itself but the calling client. And last but not least, this piece of security is actually a requirement for a few specific calls (CORS, CSRF protection and spring cloud credentials are configured). Your comments, alongside some extra research, helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research and thanks to @Toerktumlare 's comments, and figured what was happening and what I changed/applied to this.

So for the '`onComplete()`' log, it marks the end of a producer of data. So to see the full stack of the operation, I needed to chain each producer with its own log. For example:

```
Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE)
    .log()
    .flatMap(booleanVal -> Mono.just(booleanVal.toString()))
    .log()
    .subscribe(stringVal -> System.out.println("This is the boolean value " + stringVal));
```

That will produce the trace for the initial producer and the flatMap operation.

Now, onto the main problem, the issue was within the `getRequestExchange` method:

```
//gets the body as string.
private static Mono<String> getRequestExchange(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> securedReq) {

        return securedReq.exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
    }
```

The problem was hidden in the `bodyToMono` method. According to this site https://medium.com/@jeevjyotsinghchhabda/dont-let-webclient-s-bodytomono-trick-you-645123b3e0a9 , if the response to this request has no body for whatever reason, will not throw any error, but just return a `Mono.empty()`. Since that the flow was not prepared for such a producer, it ended right there.

In my case, the problem was spring cloud security. I provided the Authorization credential, but not the associated SESSION cookie in the request. So the request returned a 302 (Found) without body. That was the problem (not the reactive flow itself).

So, after that, I modified the request, and @Toerktumlare 's comments helped me develop a working solution:

```
//service that returns if certain resource needs authentication or not, or if it's not even configured
return accessPointService.getAccessPointAuthorizationRequirement(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getMethod().toString().toUpperCase(), FWKUtils.translateAccessPointPath(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getPath().pathWithinApplication().elements()))
                //if the response is a Mono Empty, then returns a not acceptable exception
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> throwNotAcceptable(serverWebExchange)))
                //takes the boolean value to check if extra auth is needed.
                .flatMap(isRequired -> validateAuthenticationRequirement(isRequired))
                //gets the access token - the extra auth credential
                .flatMap(isRequired -> getHeaderToken(serverWebExchange))
                //from this access generates a WebClient to the specific authentication service - from a webClientProvider to not create too many WebClients.
                .flatMap(accessToken -> generateAuthenticationRequest(webClientProvider.getInstance(), accessToken))
                //gets the CRSF token credential and secures the request (adds it to the header and the cookies)
                .zipWith(getCredential(webClientProvider.getInstance(), "csrf"), (securedRequest, csrfToken) -> secureAuthenticationRequest(securedRequest, csrfToken, "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "XSRF-TOKEN"))
                //gets the SESSION (spring cloud security) token credential and secures the request (adds it to the header and the cookies)
                .zipWith(getCredential(webClientProvider.getInstance(), "spring-cloud"), (securedRequest, sessionToken) -> secureAuthenticationRequest(securedRequest, sessionToken, "Authorization", "SESSION"))
                //does the request and gets the response
                .map(requestBodySpecs -> requestBodySpecs.retrieve())
                //from the response, maps it to a specific DTO. The single() clause is to validate that a body is present.
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(SecurityCredentialResponseDTO.class).single())
                //checks the authentication and throws a Unauthorizedstatus if its not valid.
                .flatMap(responseDTO -> checkTokenAuthentication(serverWebExchange, responseDTO))
                //if an error is present, then throws it 
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    if (e instanceof FWKException.GenericException) {
                        throw (FWKException.GenericException) e;
                    }
                    throw (RuntimeException) e;
                })
                //finally, continues the execution if no exception was thrown.
                .then(webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange));
```

There's a bit more that I implemented in this solution (storing the CSRF and spring-cloud credential to avoid innecesary calls).